# How to throw an error if value not found in JSON (JSONata)

Tags: jsonata

Is there way to throw an error if value not found?

JSON:

```
{
  "qty": 2
}
```

JSONata:
`"order=" & order & ",qty=" & qty`

If `order` is not in JSON, empty value will be used. I would like to throw an error if value not exist, for example something like this:

`"order=" & $not_empty(order) & ",qty=" & qty`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is `$assert` function.

more info here: https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/issues/167

unfortunately I did not found it JSONata documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [$error](https://docs.jsonata.org/object-functions#error) function which use could use with the `$exists` function to create your own implementation if `$not_empty`. E.g.:

```
(
    $not_empty := function($val) { $exists($val) ? $val : $error("Missing!")};
    "order=" & $not_empty(order) & ",qty=" & qty
)
```